# Insert multiple rows in SQLite (WIndows phone 7 & 8)

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am  creating  a table  named  "Task" with four  columns by taking  a  new class

```
 public sealed class Task
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

}
```

To  insert  single  row..i  followed  this..it  working  perfectly

```
private void Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
        {

            db.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                db.Insert(new Task() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Ken", LastName = d1[2], CreationDate = DateTime.Now });

          });

        }
    }
```

..but  in  my  requirement ..i  have  to  insert  multiple rows  at  a  time..i tried  the  following.

```
private void Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    //perfectly  working
    {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
        {

            db.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                db.Insert(new Task() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Ken", LastName = d1[2], CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
                 db.Insert(new Task() { Id = 2, FirstName = "Justin", LastName = "Bieber", CreationDate = DateTime.Now });

                db.Insert(new Task() { Id = 3, FirstName = "king", LastName = "john", CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
            });

        }
    }
```

when  i   followed  this,no  error  popped..but   only    first  row  is  inserting..  no  sign  of  second  row  details..
please  help me  in this  regard..

Answer (score 1):

I think "Task" is your model.
Try to have a ViewModel who will contain your functions for Insert, Update,Delete in your DataBase.

DatabaseViewModel:

```
public void Insert(Task test)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    dbConn.Insert(test);
                });
        }
    }
```

And then :

```
private void Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
 {
    DatabaseViewModel _dbHelper = new DatabaseViewModel();
    _dbHelper.Insert(new Task(1, "justin", "Bieber", DateTime.Now);
    _dbHelper.Insert(new Task(2, "Cristiano" "Ronaldo", DateTime.Now);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare 3 arrays (1 for id, 1 for FirstName and 1 for LastName) and add a foreach in your method.

```
//Arrays declaration
int[] IDs = {1, 2, 3};
string[] FirstNames = {"Ken", "Justin", "King"};
string[] LastNames = {"Barbie", "Bieber", "Kong"};
```

and after

```
private void Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
        {
            using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
            {
                db.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    foreach(int id in IDs)
                    {
                        db.Insert(new Task() { IDs[id-1], FirstNames[id-1], LastNames[id-1], CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

I hope it could help...

Comment: Can  you  provide  some  more  Info...                                                            Its   throwing  error  at  this  particular  line.    .                                                                                                                                   db.Insert(new Task() { IDs[id-1], FirstNames[id-1], LastNames[id-1], CreationDate = DateTime.Now });

Answer (score 0):

have you tried by running separate `RunInTransaction` for all insert operation. like below:

```
        db.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
            db.Insert(new Task() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Ken", LastName = d1[2], CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
        });

        db.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
             db.Insert(new Task() { Id = 2, FirstName = "Justin", LastName = "Bieber", CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
        });

        db.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
            db.Insert(new Task() { Id = 3, FirstName = "king", LastName = "john", CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
        });
```

this might help..
let me know further.

Comment: Its not  working  ....can you elaborate..do  u have  any other  alternative  ideas